# OkHttp - 404 Not Found

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using `OkHttpClient` to get `API` key but getting Response

```
{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://unknown.com/api.php}
```

below code, I am using.

```
OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient();
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = 
HttpUrl.parse("https://unknown.com/api").newBuilder();
                urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("os_version", "Android 25");
                urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("user_id", "12345");
                urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("device", "Android");

                String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();
                try{
                    Response response = client1.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.e("response",""+ response.body().string());

                }catch (Exception e){
                   Log.e("MSG",""+e.getMessage());
                }
```

Previously, I was using namevalue pair but it was working only for `6.0` and above not for 5.0 so I switched to `OkHttp` but not able to get correct response.
I am following

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

**Log:**

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://unknown.com/api.php}
```

Comment: Make sure you have to configure your server properly?
Have you check it on Postman?

Comment: https://secure.unknownphone.com/api.php Url its giving 404 in the browser.So please check URL working properly in Postman

Comment: Yes, it's working properly when I use namevaluepair but not in android 5.0(was getting no peer certificate). so I am trying to use Okhttp. and last parameter is "_action","_get_new_api_key".

Comment: @AshishJain Did u solve it?

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj I have fixed it without using OkHttpClient.

Comment: @AshishJain how did you fix it, please?